# DateTime.TryParseExact failing with seemingly correct format C#

Tags: c#, datetime, date-parsing

I have the following code in a test project that I'm working on. Trouble is, `TryParseExact` keeps displaying an error instead of parsing my date correctly and storing in the `dParsedDate` variable. What am I doing wrong here? I can't see any issues with my format pattern so I'm at a loss here.

```
string sDateTime = "2015-09-15 09:09:09";
string sPattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
DateTime dParsedDate;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(sDateTime, sPattern, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dParsedDate))
    textBox2.Text = "ERROR";
else
    textBox2.Text = dParsedDate.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [no `YYYY` format string for `DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). Use lowercase `y`'s.

```
string sPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you! Boy do I feel like a dummy.

Answer (score 0):

As per msdn documentation at [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime dParsedDate;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(sDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dParsedDate))
textBox2.Text = "ERROR";
else
textBox2.Text = dParsedDate.ToString();
```